# Is there a graphical summary of which modulation technique to use in communication systems using Visible Light Communication techniques?

Tags: laser, power, error-analysis, signal-processing, noise

I am currently looking at various papers written (some listed at the bottom) that discuss how laser pulses can be modulated to send encoded messages to a receiver for communication systems. The more I read , the more I find out there are many ways to do this.  From what I have seen there are 4 major categories of modulation schemes:

1) Pulse Position Modulation (PPM)

2) Pulse Amplitude Modulation (PAM)

3) Frequency Modulation (FM)

4) Phase Shift Modulation (PSM)

As I read through more and more papers, I am seeing that people have improved on various parameters in 1-4 above (average power, period of pulses, bit error rate, packet error rate, and signal-to-noise ratio SNR to name a few). As a result, each of the 4 categories above has maybe 100s modulation schemes that improve on various parameters.

I am wondering if there is a tree diagram of sorts that guides which modulation scheme to use depending on your needs.  For example, suppose I need a low bit error rate but messages need to be sent as quickly as possible and power is not a concern, how do I know which modulation scheme is best?

Or, another example, suppose power IS a concern, but speed of messages being sent to the receiver is not. How do I know which modulation scheme is best?

The closest diagram I found for what I am looking for can be found [here](https://www.electronicshub.org/modulation-and-different-types-of-modulation/):

[image]

But this diagram is missing guidance about which schemes to use for your specific needs.

Is there a diagram out there is fills in details about this?

Following are just some of the papers I have looked at:

https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-19-26-B868

https://tmo.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-161/161T.pdf

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1143/JJAP.37.L492/meta